# How to find longest common suffix from a list of strings and return the resulting suffix length in java?

Tags: java, string, suffix

Consider the following in a ArrayList or LinkedList:
[Gloucestershire, Hampshire, Yorkshire, Lancashire]
shire is the longest common suffix of length 5. 
The output should be 5
How can I write a method to achieve the above and return length

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: first check the last elem of all strings, then 2nd last and so on

Comment: I have tried with two strings and not a list of strings. The following url was helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839443/how-to-find-common-suffix-in-java-by-using-method

Comment: Don't know why they reverse them but whatever. Implement a solution that checks only the first 2 strings then think how you can iterate over the list to check all the strings. If you will have a specific problem at that point come back here with some code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

 Explanation is in the comments

```
package javaapplication1;
public class SegmentTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"Gloucestershire", "Hampshire", "Yorkshire", "Lancashire"};
        int i,j;
        int min=10000000;

        //reversing the strings and finding the length of smallest string
        for(i=0;i<(array.length);i++)
        {
          if(array[i].length()<min)
              min=array[i].length();


         StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder();
         input1.append(array[i]);
         array[i] = input1.reverse().toString();
        }

        //finding the length of longest suffix

        for(i=0;i<min;i++)
        {
          for(j=1;j<(array.length);j++)
          {
              if(array[j].charAt(i)!=array[j-1].charAt(i))
              {
                break;
              }
          }
          if(j!=array.length)
              break;
        }

        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is,first checking the last elem of all strings, then 2nd last and so on.

**Time Complexity: O(n*m)**, 
n=number of strings, m=length of smallest string

Comment: @shriharis my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Guava has a helper function called [`Strings.commonSuffix(CharSequence a, CharSequence b)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html) that could be used in your algorithm. I know adding dependency like Guava only to have this function can be overkill - in this case you can take a look at the source code to see [how this function is implemented](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Strings.java#L199) and you can move this implementation to your program. Then your program could look like this:

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CommonSuffixLengthMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        assert 5 == commonSuffixLength(Arrays.asList("Gloucestershire", "Hampshire", "Yorkshire", "Lancashire"));

        assert 2 == commonSuffixLength(Arrays.asList("abc", "dbc", "qebc", "webc"));

        assert 0 == commonSuffixLength(Collections.emptyList());

        assert 0 == commonSuffixLength(Collections.singletonList("abc"));

        assert 0 == commonSuffixLength(Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "zxc"));
    }

    private static int commonSuffixLength(final List<String> strings) {
        int result = 0;

        if (strings == null || strings.size() < 2) {
            return result;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.size() - 1; i++) {
            String prefix = Strings.commonSuffix(strings.get(i), strings.get(i + 1));
            result = result == 0 ?
                    prefix.length() :
                    Math.min(prefix.length(), result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail for {'abc','dbc','qebc','webc'}

Comment: @TanujYadav Thanks for pointing that out. Edited the answer to support this case as well.